# netty compress self defined package

Tags: java, netty

I use `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` to decode my package which the format is:

```
| len(4 bytes) | cmd(2 bytes) | binary data(variable length which is the value of "len") |
```

The `cmd` means the request code which is fixed 2 bytes.

Sometimes, the binary data might too big, and I want to compress it into:

```
| len(4 bytes) | cmd(2 bytes) | compressed data(cmd + binary data) |
```

The `cmd` behind `len` set to an constant value like 100 which denote the data parts was compressed.

Now I handmade this in my own package encoder handler. I want to ask can this be done by netty's handler like `ZlibEncoder`?

Like:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyPackageEncoder());
ch.pipeline().addLast(new ZlibEncoder());
```

But the problem is, `ZlibEncoder` will compress whole package data including the `len` segment, this is unwanted or else the boundary of data will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by `ZlibEncoder`. You will need to hand-roll your own compression codec.